# How $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^c}{c^x}=0$, for $c>1$

Tags: limits

How $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^c}{c^x}=0$, for $c>1$,

L'Hospital's rule doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Some intuition: every time you double the value of $x$, the numerator is multiplied by a factor $2^c$. The denominator is squared. Once the two become big enough, one of those operations is a _lot_ more powerful than the other.

Comment: Try to use logarithm.

Comment: @Arthur thanks for intuitive insight.

Comment: @Falang yes, as Logarithm(of above function) is approaching to a  more negative number, that means that original function is approaching to zero. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^c = e^{c\ln x}, c^x = e^{x\ln c}$